# How can i get original purchase date of app purchase in iOS Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, in-app

I want to convert my app from paid app to free app with IAP. I also do not want to betray the users which already has bought it, so I thought to implement a check where who already have bought the App, don't need to purchase the in-App payment to unlock all.

Now how can i check user has already purchase the app. Based on which value of receipt is use for check user has already purchased or not.

Comment: You can't get the purchase date but you can get the original application version from the receipt. This field contains the `CFBundleVersion`, aka the "build" number in Xcode.  You need to make sure that your build following for the free release is different to any previous build numbers so that you can identify paid users.

Comment: @Paulw11 but in receipt data i get "original_purchase_date_ms" key value. so why i can't use this?

Comment: From memory that field applies to in app purchases, not the app purchase

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for answer. I have one more confusion regarding original application version. if i install paid app (assume version is 2.2.1). Now i uninstall the app. After some days install new app it is now free app (assume version is 3.2.1). So now what is the value of  original application version when install new free app.

Comment: It will be 2.2.1

Comment: @PaulSchröder thank you so much for answer.

Comment: I am doing exactly this as well. There’s no answer that has been accepted so I wanted to ask if this worked out. Did this work out for you?